# Is there any difference between 'attack on titan' and 'attack titan'?

Tags: prepositions

Attack on titan is a manga series written and illustrated by janpaness.

I wonder why the title is 'attack on titan' not 'attack titan'.

 cf. The man attacked him with a knife.

I think attack is 'transitive verb' so, 'on' is not necessary.
Why does the title need 'on'?

Is there any difference(or nuance) between 'attack on titan' and 'attack titan'?

Comment: I think the original Japanese author came up with the English title.  I'm afraid it doesn't really make sense in English.  When I first saw the title "Attack on Titan", I thought it would be some kind of space opera—I imagined a military assault on Saturn's moon Titan.

Comment: For more detail about the meaning of the English vs Japanese titles, and the problems with the English, there is this question. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/why-is-shingeki-no-kyojin-translated-as-attack-on-titan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder why the title is 'attack on titan' not 'attack titan'.

In *Attack on Titan*, the word *attack* is a [noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun), whereas in *attack Titan* it is a [verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb).

We would usually use an article before the noun *attack*:

> **The** attack on Titan

or,

> **An** attack on Titan

but in headlines and titles articles are often omitted.

The preposition *on* is used to characterize the attack. We cannot combine the preposition *on* and the verb *attack* and thus link the verb to its object:

> Attack **on** that trench, boys! (* the sentence is ungrammatical)

but

> The US army launched an attack **on** Midway. (the sentence is OK)